# How to disable Xcode 5 automatically upgrade xibs to iOS7 appearance

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xib, appearance, xcode5

If you open an Xcode 4.x project at Xcode 5 and then open a xib at Interface Builder, you will get an alert:

[image: XCode ask to upgrade pre iOS7 xibs to iOS7 only]

**NOTE: I only have the issues with the forced iOS7 appearance, auto layout is still turned off for me.**

And then i accidentally clicked "Alway Upgrade" so Xcode automatically upgrades all my xibs to Xcode 5 and iOS7 prior. But i use Xcode 4.x parallel and it's very annoying to switching back all the xibs when i accidentally open them in Xcode 5.

Before opened in XCode 5 interface builder:

[image: Interface Builder Document with opens in XCode 4.6 and View as 6.1 and earlier]

After opened in XCode 5 interface builder:

[image: Interface Builder Document with opens in XCode 5.0 and View as 7.0 and later]

I searched in Xcode and on Google to get the way to turn this "feature" off, but i still have no luck about it.

Comment: I just reset changes of .xib on GIT repository, but I also need more workaround about that

Comment: I do the same, but every time i click on a xib the whole procedure start over because of "Always Upgrade" option... really annoying i can't find that option to turn off

Comment: Any solution? im in the same boat here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the File Inspector for the xib (<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>opt</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>), you can change the "Opens in" popup to say "Xcode 4.6".  This will revert the document format to one that is compatible with Xcode 4.6, but it also means you will not be able to take advantage of some of the new capabilities in Xcode with regards to xibs.

---

If you want to "reset" the "Always upgrade" choice you made, you can do that by resetting that particular user default using Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.xcode IBAlwaysUpgradeAutolayoutDocuments -bool false
```

Comment: I already know that
"But i use Xcode 4.x parallel and it's very annoying to switching back all the xibs when i accidentally open them in Xcode 5."

Comment: Stil no luck with that line, the problem is not about the auto layout, check my edit please.

Comment: @TussLászló changing this setting would probably require quitting Xcode before running the command.

Comment: The command doesn't work here either, also after closing Xcode. Might there be a flag in the project file?

Comment: No more headache after changing the "Opens in" option to Xcode 4.6, thank you.

Comment: 2013-12-04 13:11:17.048 defaults[2060:507] 
Rep argument is not a dictionary
Defaults have not been changed.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the above solutions, but as other users pointed out, didn't seem to work well... Strangely, after downloading [Cocktail for Mac](http://www.maintain.se/cocktail), and cleaning up broken preference as well as caches and other junk (which I did just to maintain my aging Mac) the "Always Upgrade" mistake was finally fixed!!

I haven't bought cocktail, honestly, you can use it for free for ten launches or something. So, you can go ahead and get your Mac cleaned up and fix that burden along the way.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the Dave DeLong's command to reset the "Always upgrade". Try it.

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.xcode IBAlwaysUpgradeAutolayoutDocuments -boolean false
```

Comment: Same issue, please check my added note.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't have luck with either of these commands, but this one worked for me...

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.xcode IBAlwaysUpgradeAutolayoutDocuments -int 0
```