# xib edit getting crash in xcode5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode5

I have an application which is totally developed in `xcode 4.6` ad now it is in app store also. Now i'm going to update the app in iOS7 also for that i upgraded my mac OS and xcode. my mac OS version is 10.8.5 and i installed `xcode 5` also. Now my problem is xcode getting crash immediately when i edit and save the `xib`.

I tried all these ways.
1. [Xcode 5 crashes -- Xcode quit unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18905900/1160493)
2. uninstall my xcode completely using this `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all` and install again

Comment: Remove OLD XIB and create new one for it...surly work it out.

Comment: my project contains more number of xib with lot of UI design. If i do this,again it will take the time as complete redevelopment

Comment: that means this was happened in all XIB ?

Comment: Any error you are facing or any stack trace where it is crashing? try to debug the application if you find something share it. In my case custon uipagecontrol is crashing the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

When you open a xib file that was created in Xcode 4 in Xcode 5 you are prompted to upgrade the file to the new format. You want to only do it if all the people working on the project use Xcode 5 because the new files can’t be opened by older versions of Xcode.

**Refer this links :**

[How to disable Xcode 5 automatically upgrade xibs to iOS7 appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718715/how-to-disable-xcode-5-automatically-upgrade-xibs-to-ios7-appearance)

http://nilsou.com/blog/2013/08/07/xcode-5-finally-makes-interface-builder-a-viable-option-for-teams/

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: while installing  xcode 5 i totally uninstalled xcode 4.6 so there is nothing to be prompted to upgrade the xib file to the new format

Answer (score 0):

Yes this was the problem with Xcode version DP4 and DP5. IF you are using these version then your Xcode5 will get crashed while adding/Editing XIB"S. I guess you should  use Full version XCODE5 . This problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your simulator. And delete old app in simulator. I think this may work.